# Drop Shadow from a Div onto an Image Element in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been having this problem with a navigation bar and the image element that is directly below it. Basically, I want the shadow from the bar to emit onto the image. I've tried to use position: relative on the image element, but when I do that it makes the image disappear...

When I put my code into jsfiddle it works how I want it to, but in Chrome it doesn't show the image at all.

I enclose the image link in the div element called "Banner". You can see the whole shabang here: http://jsfiddle.net/g09uagyr/

```
#Banner{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;  /*display as block element */
  /*box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px black;*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Any help I can get would be awesome!

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Seems to work in my chrome, 41.0.2272.76 (64-bit), so what version of chrome and FF are you using?

Comment: So your saying the fiddle you provided works like you want it to work but in your real site in Chrome it doesn't and the image is not visible? Then I would suspect some other element which is not in your fiddle is over the image. Try to give your image a higher `z-index` and your `#nav` and even higher so it stays on top (ie 100 for `#Banner` and 101 for `#nav`).

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: seems working on my chrome too, my chrome is of Version 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks @Jey DWork, I did what you suggested and it worked. Can I give you credit?

Comment: @Kemal Talen I'm glad it worked. I've added it as answer. You may accept it if you like ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the comment: Your `#Banner` has a `z-index` of -1 which means other elements which may be there but not in your fiddle (like for example a non transparent container or body) can overlay it and that causes your `#Banner` to disappear.

To solve this give it a higher `z-index` and elements you still want over your `#Banner` like your `#nav` an even higher one. For example 100 as `z-index` for `#Banner` and 101 for `#nav`.

Comment: Good explanation - but, please, lower your z-values to *realistic* ones. I.e. within the range of -2 -> 8, not crazy ones like '100'. When have you ever wanted to layer 99 other elements below this? If you ever had, I think you should take another look at your DOM, since it could probably do with a bit of help..

Comment: I use such high z-values because I'm used to work with frameworks (mainly bootstrap). Those have quite a few own z-index elements where their "low priority" ones normally are between 10 and 90 and their "high priority" ones (modal overlays etc) on 1000+. So using 100+ for my own has proven to be quite collision free. Besides, what would be the disadvantages of using high values even if you are not planning to use a framework at any point? And to allow yourself room for modifications 1-steps wouldn't be good practices anyways and with 10-steps you'd at most have 9 but 99 elements below ;-)